# Trying to iterate through an array and add a get function for each

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, express, closures

I want to iterate through the style tags and write a GET function for each. The problem is the GET function is being written with a reference to 'styleTags[i]' instead of converting 'styleTags[i]' to the appropriate tag.

```
var styleTags = ['cont', 'ecce'];

for (var i = 0; i < styleTags.length; i++) {
  app.get('/photos-' + styleTags[i], selectNav, function(req, res) {
    getDynPhotos(req, res, styleTags[i]);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what  problem you are asking about, but I do see an issue with your use of `i` in the callback.  Because `app.get()` is presumably asynchronous and will complete some time later, the value of `i` will not still be valid.  You need to create a closure that will capture the value of `i`.  There are several ways to do that.   Here's one way using an immediately invoked function expression (often abbreviated IIFE):

```
var styleTags = ['cont', 'ecce'];

for (var i = 0; i < styleTags.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
      app.get('/photos-' + styleTags[index], selectNav, function(req, res) {
        getDynPhotos(req, res, styleTags[index]);
      });
  })(i);
}
```

This will freeze the value of `i` in the function argument that I've named `index` so it will still have the right value at the later time when the callback is called.

If this isn't what you were asking about (though it is still something that needs to be fixed), then please describe in more detail what you were asking about.

Comment: Is there an FAQ here somewhere? This question comes up just about every single day.

Comment: This answers exactly what I was asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a for loop in Node because it doesn't create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). Instead, I recommend [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each):

```
var async = require('async');
var styleTags = ['cont', 'ecce'];

async.each(styleTags, function(styleTag, callback) {
  app.get('/photos-' + styleTag, selectNav, function(req, res) {
    getDynPhotos(req, res, styleTag);
  });
callback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to build a Node.js Express route.

I'm somewhat surprised this didn't work, as I thought the declaration of these routes would be synchronous.

Could you look at `app.routes` to see what Node is putting in place for you? I'm guessing you may have done this already, but I thought I'd mention it.

I have two suggestions if that doesn't work: use regular expressions in your route to isolate the category section of your route (then validate the route at request time), or insert your route directly into the `app.routes` object structure.